# Memory leak in boost::regex library

Tags: c++, windows, boost, memory-leaks, mfc

I'm not big on the Boost library. I need it for a regular expression matching in my legacy C++/MFC project that is compiled in the VS 2008.

Here's a short code snippet:

```
//Need Unicode support
CString ss;
boost::tregex r(L"<(From )?([A-Za-z0-9_]+)>(.*?)");
boost::tmatch what;
CString chat_input(L"<Darker> Hello");
if(boost::regex_match(chat_input, what, r))     //Memory leak on this line
{
    // extract $1 as a CString:
    ss = L"Match";//CString(what[1].first, what.length(1));
}
else
{
    ss = L"No match";
}
```

When I run that in a debug mode, I get the following in the output window:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{287} normal block at 0x00460068, 4096 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 00 00 00 00 CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
Object dump complete.
```

And if I comment out the `boost::regex_match` line, the leak goes away.

What am I missing here?

PS. The version of boost that I'm linking to is 1_55_0.

Comment: Put the above code in a loop, iterate 10 times (say), now do you get 10 blocks in your memory leak report? If not then I don't think it's a memory leak. Some libraries make one off allocations of memory which they never free.

Comment: @john, what is it then?

Comment: As I said, it may be a one-off allocation of memory that never gets freed. That's not really a memory leak, since the memory will always be recovered on program exit. Only a theory, check it out like I said.

Comment: @john: That is a very bad approach to memory management.

Comment: @john: So what you're saying is that the code I gave above is semantically correct and that there's something in the boost library itself that sieves memory, correct?

Comment: The issue is rather more involved. MFC checks for memory leaks when its library is unloaded. Now MFC believes that it is always the last library to unload. If you add another library to the mix, certain assumptions no longer hold, and MFC may report a false positive.

Comment: @IInspectable: OK, I see your point. So is there any way to have boost unloaded before MFC? To be honest with you I do rely on those debugger messages of memory leaks.

Comment: You could manually load and unload the boost library using [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx) and [`FreeLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152.aspx), marking the dependency as a *delay load* library. I'm not sure this will work. It's worth a try, though - MFC's and the CRT's leak checking are very valuable tools.

Comment: @IInspectable: Bummer... I'm linking to it statically.

Comment: Just to make sure we are talking about the same thing: Are you statically linking against a .dll or are you linking with the static library?

Comment: Another option you might want to consider: Starting with Visual Studio 2008 the compiler comes with [`<regex>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982382%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). It parses [TR1 Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982727%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), and likely plays along better with MFC than a 3rd party library.

Comment: @IInspectable: I'm talking about linking with a static library. And as for the built-in regex in TR1, then I can't use TR1. Besides ballooning the statically linked MFC code, it makes compiled exe's not compatible with Win2K, which I have to support in this legacy code. Thus I have to look into Boost. I'm curious now if it's possible to disable those debugger memory allocation checks just for the Boost library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to resolve this. Still couldn't just ignore it since it was way too easy to ignore possible other memory leaks during the development process.

The solution that worked for me was to create a standalone C/C++-only Dll project and export all the needed Boost functionality from it, that in turn can be used from the MFC project as a shared library. (This makes it a concise version of Boost.)

If anyone else finds a way to get rid of this memory leak warning, please post it here. Until than, this is my answer...

Answer (score 0):

The unit testing framework [CppUnit](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/lastest/index.html), also complains about "memory leaks" in the `boost::regex` library.

I believe that it's because the `boost::regex` implementation uses a static member variable, like a "Meyers" singleton, and the memory leak detection doesn't like it. There's nothing wrong with boost library, it's certainly *not* leaking memory!

In MSVC 2010 onwards you can use `std::regex` instead which I can assure you does not report any leaks. In MSVC 2008 you should be able to use `std::tr1::regex`, but I don't have any experience of it I'm sorry to say.